# Spark inner joins results in empty records

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql, inner-join

I'm performing an inner join between dataframes to only keep the sales for specific days:

```
val days_df = ss.createDataFrame(days_array.map(Tuple1(_))).toDF("DAY_ID")
val filtered_sales = sales.join(days_df,Seq("DAY_ID")
filtered_sales.show()
```

This results in an empty `filtered_sales` dataframe (0 records), both columns `DAY_ID` have the same type (`string`).

```
root
|-- DAY_ID: string (nullable = true)

root
|-- SKU: string (nullable = true)
|-- DAY_ID: string (nullable = true)
|-- STORE_ID: string (nullable = true)
|-- SALES_UNIT: integer (nullable = true)
|-- SALES_REVENUE: decimal(20,5) (nullable = true)
```

The `sales` df is populated from a 20GB file.

Using the same code with a small file of some KB will work fine with the join and I can see the results. The empty result dataframe occurs only with bigger dataset.

If I change the code and use the following one, it works fine even with the 20GB sales file:

```
sales.filter(sales("DAY_ID").isin(days_array:_*))
.show()
```

What is wrong with the inner join?

Comment: can you print schema of both DFs you're joining too?

Comment: Hi I updated the question to add the schema :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to broadcast **days_array** and then apply inner join. As days_array is too small compared to another table, broadcasting will help.